# Return Json Format to View - MVC

Tags: json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to asp.net MVC. I hav to return `Json` from controller to view using `ajax` call, that is perfect.

I want to return below json format to view.

```
 [{
    "name": "A", 
    "data": [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.4, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6] },
  { 
    "name": "B", 
    "data": [3.9, 2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  },
  { 
    "name": "C", 
    "data": [3.9, 2, 5.7, 8.5, 11.9, 15.2, 17.0, 16.6, 14.2, 10.3, 6.6, 4.8]
  }]
```

I have tried below modal to return such a format,

```
public class myModel
    {
        public List<string> Name { get; set; }
        public List<float> Average { get; set; }
    }
```

What should be my model like to return above mentioned format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MyModel` should be modified like this

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<float> data { get; set; }
}
```

as `name` property is only for a single `string`, and `data` is actually the array holding the `float` values.
You can return `List<MyModel>` or array - `MyModel[]` as `JSON` from `ajax` call

Answer (score 0):

model type should be:

```
public class myModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<float> data { get; set; }
}
```

AND in Controller:

```
List<myModel> list=new List<myModel>();

return new JsonResult()
{
       Data = list,
       JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
       MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue
 };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<float> Data { get; set; }
}

public JsonResult MyMethod() 
{
    List<MyModel> list = new List<MyModel>();
    // Do stuff
    return Json(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Viewmodel:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public List<MyModel> myModel {get;set;}

}
```

myModel should be like this:

```
public class myModel
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public IList<double> data { get; set; }
    }
```

You can easily generate this kind of task with [jsonutils](http://jsonutils.com/) online.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be like this.

```
public class myModel
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<double> data { get; set; }
}
```

Here `name` contain single string value and data is contain array of `double` value.

**Note** : Use `json2charp` to convert your `JSON to c#` class type or if you are using `vs2013` or above version paste copied `JSON in C#` class type.